# Is there an inbuilt way to pause an AIR Desktop App?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, desktop-application, suspend

I have an AIR Desktop Game that has background music and in the main menu repeating animations. Is there an inbuilt possibility to tell the AIR container, that when the window loses focus (e.g. through alt+tab or when pressing the windows key), that the AIR container is then pausing the content of its container (pausing music and animations/frameHandlers etc.)?

Or is it only possible by stopping all contents one by one and when getting focus again, start all things one by one?

Comment: The latter. You'll have to listen for `Event.ACTIVATE` and `Event.DEACTIVATE` on the stage or `NativeApplication` and stop everything one-by-one and then restart them all afterward.

Comment: Seriously?! Shouldn't there be some kind of functionality for this in the AIR container? T_T
Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: Adobe doesn't automate anything. Flash/AIR isn't meant to be an easy SDK with a bunch of helpers and everything. It's meant to be a language that gives the developer absolute control over. Think about it, though, how would they pause it? How often would someone want an absolutely static screen with no sound or anything? To the user, the app would appear frozen (which, technically, it is). Plus it wouldn't interact properly with system interaction (i.e. scrolling an inactive window in OS X) and would actually go against most design paradigms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @JoshJanusch said is true -- you will have to manage it yourself, though setting `stage.frameRate` might help in your case.

Most activate/deactivate managers I've seen do some of the following:

- Set `stage.frameRate` to 0.01 (slows animations and `ENTER_FRAME` event listeners, saving CPU/battery especially on mobile)
- Stop sounds (if you play all sounds through some `SoundManager` class, this may be easy)
- Manage your use of `setInterval` or `setTimeout` as they're Timers that continue to fire
- Consider suspending any other asynchronous activity (like network requests or background `Workers`)

Feel free to make suggestions for this list in the comments.

Comment: Oh this comes in handy, thanks a lot. Is there a reason why to set the framerate to 0.01?

Comment: That's the lowest valid value per [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#frameRate)  =)

Comment: This is a good answer, though setting the framerate to 0.01 *will* still cause animations to move (an animation that should move 1 pixel a second will move 1 pixel every 100 seconds, for example). You'll probably want to handle that. If this is a game, you should have a pause menu anyway that you can use when `Event.DEACTIVATE` fires.

Comment: Right - game frameworks should have a pause mechanism (or respect deactivate events automatically, like [Starling's Juggler class](http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/starling/animation/Juggler.html)), and it's best to use (sound, animation, timer, etc) frameworks that support pause as well.  The frameRate trick may benefit items that doesn't use these.